# .click function with an Ajax post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, button

So I got a select menu and when an user select an option, it calls a post function via ajax that generates some table rows via PHP and then it returns the html coding for it. In it, there is an Add button.

What I am trying to do is that when the user clicks the add button, a form shows up.
But for some reason, it is not working...

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".add_form").hide();

    $("#console").change(function () {
        var id = $(this).val();
        var dataString = 'console_id=' + id;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "generate-games-list",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                $("#games_table_body").html(html);
            }
        });

    });

    $(".add_button").click(function () {
        alert("HELLO");
        var id = this.id;

        $.post('manage_games', 'game_id=' + id, function (response) {
            alert(response);
        });

        $("#game_id").val(id);
        $(".add_form").show();

    });

});
```

Here is the PHP code that returns the table rows:

```
$console = Console::find(Input::get('console_id'));
    $type = GameType::find(Input::get('type_id'));

    if(!Input::has('console_id'))
        return "Error";
    else{

        foreach($console->games()->get() as $console_game){
            $available_consoles_string = "";
            $game_types_string = "";

            //Get all the consoles the game can be played on
            foreach($console_game->consoles()->orderBy('name', 'asc')->get() as $available_consoles){
                $available_consoles_string = $available_consoles_string . " " .$available_consoles->name .", ";
            }

            //Get all the types that the game falls in
            foreach($console_game->types()->orderBy('type', 'asc')->get() as $game_types){
                $game_types_string = $game_types_string . " " .$game_types->type .", ";
            }   

            return "<tr><td>" .$console_game->name. "</td><td>". $available_consoles_string. "</td><td>" .$game_types_string. "</td><td><input type='button' id='" .$console_game->id. "' class='add_button' value='Add'/> / View</td></tr>";

        }
    }
```

Any idea why it is not working? When I mean not working, I mean the alert is not showing up but I am not getting any error on the Chrome Console...

Thanks,
Ara

Comment: Use the on() method on the parent container. E.g. `$('#games_table_body').on('click', '.add_button', function() { ... });`.

Comment: You should set the click handler inside the success function of your `console.change` ajax request. On ready the button is not yet there, so the handler gets attached to nothing...

Answer (score 2):

Simply use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(document).on("click", ".add_button", function(){
    // your event code
});
```

When your js runs a `click` event is attached to all current elements with the `.add_button` class. However, you're adding extra buttons via ajax and these won't have trigger the same `click` event.

To fix this use the code above. It attaches the event to the `document` so even if you add buttons once the page has loaded the `click` event will be triggered by them.